# Duplicate file on Building project - checkQualDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

Tags: android, kotlin, build, build.gradle

I am using the below error when I build the application

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
```

Kotlin version im using is

```
 kotlin_version = '1.7.21'
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
```

Kindly help me on this its been a nightmare to understand the issue

Answer (score -1):

you can exclude one of the versions of the standard library from your dependencies. Since you're using Kotlin version 1.7.21, I recommend keeping the JDK8 version of the standard library **kotlin-stdlib-jdk8** and excluding the non-JDK8 version **kotlin-stdlib**. To do this, add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib'
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding the above im getting other exception as below
Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics